# OleVariant and SafeSysFreeString

Tags: delphi, c++builder, ole, variant, twebbrowser

If I am using `OleVariant` instead of `VARIANTARG` to store `VT_BSTR` (`VOleStr` in `OleVariant`), do I still need to call `SafeSysFreeString` when I am done with the string, or is it called automatically by OleVariant, when it goes out of scope?

For example:

```cpp
{
WB->Navigate("https://www.example.com");
while (WB->ReadyState != Shdocvw::READYSTATE_COMPLETE) Application->ProcessMessages();

DelphiInterface<IOleCommandTarget> pOleCmdTarget;
WB->Document->QueryInterface(IID_IOleCommandTarget, (void**)&pOleCmdTarget);

OleVariant v;

if (pOleCmdTarget->Exec(&CMDSETID_Forms3, IDM_FONTNAME, Shdocvw::MSOCMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, NULL, v)==S_OK)
    {
    // utilize v.VOleStr here...
    }
} // Does OleVariant auto-deallocate (SafeSysFreeString) here?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OleVariant` will automatically free its data's memory for you when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!